# How to prevent removed packages from being updated in Julia?

Tags: julia

The question's title might seem confusing at first sight, but it's valid. I installed the `Makie.jl` package a while ago, then removed it successfully using `pkg> rm Makie`. Today I tried to update all the packages, if any are available, using `pkg> up`. But I got an exciting log:

```
   ...
   Installed MLJ ────────── v0.18.6
   Installed EvoTrees ───── v0.12.4
   Installed Makie ──────── v0.18.1
    Updating `C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\environments\v1.8\Project.toml`
  [13f3f980] ↑ CairoMakie v0.9.0 ⇒ v0.9.1
  [f6006082] ↑ EvoTrees v0.12.2 ⇒ v0.12.4
  [e9467ef8] ↑ GLMakie v0.7.0 ⇒ v0.7.1
  [add582a8] ↑ MLJ v0.18.5 ⇒ v0.18.6
  [9eb5382b] ~ PkgDependency v0.2.0 `https://github.com/peng1999/PkgDependency.jl#master` ⇒ v0.2.0 `https://github.com/peng1999/PkgDependency.jl#master`
  [91a5bcdd] ↑ Plots v1.35.4 ⇒ v1.35.5
    Updating `C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\environments\v1.8\Manifest.toml`
  [13f3f980] ↑ CairoMakie v0.9.0 ⇒ v0.9.1
  [f6006082] ↑ EvoTrees v0.12.2 ⇒ v0.12.4
  [e9467ef8] ↑ GLMakie v0.7.0 ⇒ v0.7.1
  [add582a8] ↑ MLJ v0.18.5 ⇒ v0.18.6
  [d491faf4] ↑ MLJModels v0.15.14 ⇒ v0.15.15
  [ee78f7c6] ↑ Makie v0.18.0 ⇒ v0.18.1
  [20f20a25] ↑ MakieCore v0.5.0 ⇒ v0.5.1
  [91a5bcdd] ↑ Plots v1.35.4 ⇒ v1.35.5

Precompiling project...
  59 dependencies successfully precompiled in 399 seconds. 431 already precompiled. 1 skipped during auto due to previous errors.
```

As you can see, I still get updates for `Makie.jl`, and its dependencies and core stuff. So I got suspicious if I indeed removed them or not. So I tried to check it using `pkg> st Makie` and `pkg> rm Makie`, and this is the result:

```
(@v1.8) pkg> st Makie
No Matches in `C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\environments\v1.8\Project.toml`

(@v1.8) pkg> rm Makie
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * Makie (ee78f7c6-11fb-53f2-987a-cfe4a2b5a57a in manifest but not in project)

(@v1.8) pkg> rm MakieCore
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * MakieCore (20f20a25-4f0e-4fdf-b5d1-57303727442b in manifest but not in project)
```

So, according to this report, The `Makie.jl` package and its core still exist in the manifest file, leading to getting updates by `Pkg` for it and wasting much time for it to be precompiled while I don't want it at all! So the question is, "How to prevent removed packages from being updated in Julia?" or in other words, **"How to remove a package permanently in Julia?"**

Comment: This may help: https://juliapackages.com/p/pkgcleanup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 1.9 there is a `why` command:

```
(@v1.9) pkg> why Makie
  CairoMakie → Makie
```

So, it's used by CairoMakie which you have installed. If you `rm CairoMakie` too, I guess it will be gone.