# ERROR in JULIA: The following package names could not be resolved: in manifest but not in project

Tags: julia

I am trying the "DiffEqJump" package in Julia, using the command Pkg.rm("DiffEqJump") but the following error occurs:

ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:

- DiffEqJump (c894b116-72e5-5b58-be3c-e6d8d4ac2b12 in manifest but not in project)

Any idea why is this happening how to resolve it?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent removed packages from being updated in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74224274/how-to-prevent-removed-packages-from-being-updated-in-julia).Please read it to the last line, it's pretty the same question.

Comment: Apparently, it's now called [`JumpProcesses.jl`](https://github.com/SciML/JumpProcesses.jl).